# How can I avoid typing in the profile for aws each time?

Tags: sh, zsh

I want to avoid typing `--profile dev-platform` every time I want to access the AWS cli commands.

How do I add a postfix or suffix like `--profile dev-platform` every time I want to run an AWS command?

I just want to type `aws s3 ls` with out manually putting in the profile each time like the above two instances.

```
aws *wild card* --profile dev-platform
```

I tried some things like

```
alias aws= aws ** | --profile dev-platform
```

but to no avail.

Comment: You could update your `~/.aws/config` to default to that profile.

Comment: As @BenjaminW. recommended, if you run `aws configure`, you can set your default profile. Otherwise, you might want to create an alias like: `alias aws-dp 'aws --profile dev-platform'`. This has the negative impact of making scripts not portable

Comment: i just need something along the lines of `alias aws=aws "$@" echo --profile dev-platform`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple profiles in your `~/.aws/config`, and want to set `dev-platform` as the profile to use for your terminal session you can use:

```bash
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=dev-platform
```

This will set the default AWS profile to the selected profile for your terminal session.

I switch between multiple profile regularly and  create aliases for my different profiles so I can use a short command like `use-dev` to switch to my dev profile, or `use-prod`, to switch to my production profile quickly and easily without having to type the full command.